# autocomplete on a multi value - custom field

Tags: 7, users, ajax

I have a field organizations on the user profile(the field can accept multiple values). I would like to add a autocomplete to this field. My code for this is

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function org_ac_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['org_ac/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'org_ac_autocomplete',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access dbpedia autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function org_ac_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    //$form['field_organization']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'org_ac/autocomplete';
    $form['field_organization']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'org_ac/autocomplete'; **/* This works but only on the first input field! */**
  }
}

/**
 * Check for possibilities in dbpedia
 */
function org_ac_autocomplete($string = '') {
  $found = array();

  $url = 'http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/PrefixSearch?QueryString='.urlencode($string).'&MaxHits=5';
  $result = file_get_contents($url);
  $data = simplexml_load_string($result);

  foreach($data->Result as $res_temp)
  {
      $found[check_plain($res_temp->Label)] = check_plain($res_temp->Label);
  }

  drupal_json_output($found);
}
```

The code works when I reference this element on the form, ->

```
$form['field_organization']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'org_ac/autocomplete';
```

But since it can accept multiple values, the autocomplete doesn't work on the remaining elements ->`$form['field_organization']['und'][1]  &  $form['field_organization']['und'][2]['value']['value']`

How can I make it work on all the input elements for the organization field ?

Thanks

Comment: It works when i change the form element to 

$form['field_organization']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'org_ac/autocomplete';


Is there a way to have an auto complete for every field of Organization ?

Comment: Can't you just lose the check on form_id then?

Comment: That check is to ensure that its only on user profile.

Comment: I understand, what do you mean by: "Is there a way to have an auto complete for every field of Organization?" then?

Comment: My auto complete field can accept unlimited values. So there is always a possibility to add another value to the organizations field. My question is how do i set the auto complete to all the inputs fields of organization ? When I use $form['field_organization']['und'][0]['value'], it only sets auto complete to the first input field. what about the other indices ?

Comment: You should go for ahah solution then http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30689/form-field-with-support-for-multiple-values

Answer (score 2):

If you modify your hook_form_alter to loop through the $delta of field_organization it should work for you on multiples...

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function org_ac_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    foreach($form['field_organization'][LANGUAGE_NONE] as $delta => $field) {
      if(is_array($field) && is_numeric($delta)) {
        $form['field_organization'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'org_ac/autocomplete';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this will work in almost every case (+1). Chuck Norris would add another foreach() to workaround the language (`und`) as well :)

Comment: @ayesh-kLANGUAGE_NONE would be more appropriate.


$form['field_organization'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta]

Comment: JudaPriest and Ayesh K are correct. Should be using LANGUAGE_NONE or use `$lang = $form_state['values']['language'];` to grab language if multi-lingual and use `$lang` in place of LANGUAGE_NONE above.  Updated.  Thanks!